# How do I convert a datetime to date?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I convert a `datetime.datetime` object (e.g., the return value of `datetime.datetime.now())` to a `datetime.date` object in Python?

Comment: If you just need this for `datetime.datetime.now()`, please note that there is a method `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: if you have already imported datetime e.g. `from datetime import datetime` you can just add date `from datetime import datetime, date`

Answer (score 1555, accepted):

Use the [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) method:

```
datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

Comment: To get in UTC which can be very helpful --> `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` and correspondingly `datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()`

Comment: Thanks @SeanColombo, current date in a particular timezone should be `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).date()`

Comment: datetime.datetime.utcnow() is deprecated see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime
replace with datetime.now(timezone.utc).  The OP is actually after date so this is moot.

Comment: Given `from datetime import datetime, date, timezone` and one using a timezone with a non-zero offset, then `datetime.now(timezone.utc).date()` **can** be different from `datetime.now().date()` (the latter being also available as `date.today()`).

Answer (score 169):

From the documentation:

> [`datetime.datetime.date()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date)
>
> Return date object with same year, month and day.

Answer (score 78):

You use the `datetime.datetime.date()` method:

```
datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

Obviously, the expression above can (and should IMHO :) be written as:

```
datetime.date.today()
```

Comment: to be fair, this answer (using `.today()`) is the most pythonic for the stated example question.

Comment: **If you use today, be careful when comparing a date.** `today()` has an _hour_ component too. so if you do: `losdat = datetime.datetime.strptime(losdatstr, '%d%m%Y')`and then `if losdat < datetime.datetime.today():` it will always be true because `losdat`will have a time component of midnight which will fall before the timestamp of `today()`

Comment: @DennisDecoene: why use `datetime.datetime.today()` instead of `datetime.date.today()`, when one wants a `datetime.date` object?

Comment: @tzot Yes that was also what I wanted to point out but was unclear about.

Answer (score 65):

You can convert a datetime object to a date with the date() method of the date time object, as follows:

```
<datetime_object>.date()
```

Answer (score 13):

**Answer updated to Python 3.7 and more**

Here is how you can turn a date-and-time object

(aka `datetime.datetime` object, the one that is stored inside [`models.DateTimeField` django model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField))

into a date object (aka `datetime.date` object):

```
from datetime import datetime

#your date-and-time object
# let's supposed it is defined as
datetime_element = datetime(2020, 7, 10, 12, 56, 54, 324893)

# where
# datetime_element = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milliseconds)

# WHAT YOU WANT: your date-only object
date_element = datetime_element.date()
```

And just to be clear, if you print those elements, here is the output :

```
print(datetime_element)
```

> 2020-07-10 12:56:54.324893

```
print(date_element)
```

> 2020-07-10

Answer (score 12):

you could enter this code form for **(today date & Names of the Day & hour)** :
`datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S')`

'19-09-09 Mon 17:37:56'

and enter this code for (**today date simply)**:
`datetime.date.today().strftime('%y-%m-%d')`

'19-09-10'

**for object :**
`datetime.datetime.now().date()`
`datetime.datetime.today().date()`
`datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()`
`datetime.datetime.today().time()`
`datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()`
`datetime.datetime.utcnow().time()`

Comment: OP wanted to get ```datetime.date``` object, and not string, which ```strftime``` would return (ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

Answer (score 6):

```
import time
import datetime

# use mktime to step by one day
# end - the last day, numdays - count of days to step back
def gen_dates_list(end, numdays):
  start = end - datetime.timedelta(days=numdays+1)
  end   = int(time.mktime(end.timetuple()))
  start = int(time.mktime(start.timetuple()))
  # 86400 s = 1 day
  return xrange(start, end, 86400)

# if you need reverse the list of dates
for dt in reversed(gen_dates_list(datetime.datetime.today(), 100)):
    print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt).date()
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this answer here? It looks to me like you're answer is directed towards a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I use `data.strftime('%y-%m-%d')` with lambda to transfer column to date

Answer (score 0):

```
Solved: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'
```

You can use as below,

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date
```

where in above code date contains both date and time (2020-09-21 22:32:00), using above code we can get only date as (2020-09-21)

Answer (score -3):

If you are using **pandas** then this can solve your problem:

Lets say that you have a variable called start_time of type datetime64 in your dataframe then you can get the date part like this:

```
df.start_time.dt.date
```

Comment: I don't think the question was about pandas.

Comment: You are right, I had pandas on my mind when I was working on this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sance to either delete this post or clarify that. It is missleading like this.