# Days between two dates?

Tags: python, date

What's the shortest way to see how many full days have passed between two dates?
Here's what I'm doing now.

```
math.floor((b - a).total_seconds()/float(86400))
```

Comment: It's just two dates, or do they also include time information?

Comment: Ah — see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-days-betwen-two-dates-using-python

Comment: date1 = date(2018,7,3)
date2 = date(2018,9,29)
days = (date2-date1).days # days are already here

print("Total weeks {} and days {}".format(days//7, days%7));

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Assuming you’ve literally got two date objects, you can subtract one from the other and query the resulting [`timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) for the number of days:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> a = date(2011,11,24)
>>> b = date(2011,11,17)
>>> a-b
datetime.timedelta(7)
>>> (a-b).days
7
```

And it works with datetimes too — I think it rounds down to the nearest day:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime(2011,11,24,0,0,0)
>>> b = datetime(2011,11,17,23,59,59)
>>> a-b
datetime.timedelta(6, 1)
>>> (a-b).days
6
```

Comment: Coolness. Somehow I always assumed "days" refers to just the day portion of the difference. So for example difference between 2010 and 2011 would be 0 days and 1 year, but turns out it does report 365 days as I wanted.

Comment: @Bemmu: ah yes — I think `timedelta` doesn’t report any unit longer than days (although I could be wrong).

Comment: I was calculating the time difference between a few hours, something like 23 o'clock on day 1 and 01 o'clock on day 2. `timedelta` returned 0 in those cases, which is not what I wanted. I was looking for the date difference.

As a solution, I [converted the datetime to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date) and it worked as I expected!

Answer (score 47):

Do you mean full calendar days, or groups of 24 hours?

For simply 24 hours, assuming you're using Python's datetime, then the [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object already has a days property:

```
days = (a - b).days
```

For calendar days, you'll need to round a down to the nearest day, and b up to the nearest day, getting rid of the partial day on either side:

```
roundedA = a.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
roundedB = b.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
days = (roundedA - roundedB).days
```

Comment: good spot with the difference in calender days vs 24 hours. One question is why do you add 1 day. I think the above works perfectly without it.

Comment: That's the check for calendar days.  Say A is 2013-06-18 at 16:00 and B is 2013-06-19 at 02:00; one calendar day has passed, yet (B - A).days would return zero because the delta is only 10 hours.

Comment: That's the point I'm making DNS your code returns 2 because you have added another day. Without adding 1 day it returns 1. Why add a day?

Comment: See new answer with adjusted code.

Comment: Sorry, you're right; I don't know why I did that.  Updated.

Comment: Round down `a` and round up `b` => For rounding up b, we need to add timedelta(days=1) as well right? `roundedB = b.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)` rounds down B. `roundedB = b.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)` rounds up b.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
(b-a).days
```

I tried with b and a of type `datetime.date`.

Answer (score 6):

Referencing my comments on other answers. This is how I would work out the difference in days based on 24 hours and calender days. the days attribute works well for 24 hours and the function works best for calendar checks.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def cal_days_diff(a,b):

    A = a.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    B = b.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    return (A - B).days

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = datetime(2013, 06, 18, 16, 00)
    y = datetime(2013, 06, 19, 2, 00)

    print (y - x).days          # 0
    print cal_days_diff(y, x)   # 1 

    z = datetime(2013, 06, 20, 2, 00)

    print (z - x).days          # 1
    print cal_days_diff(z, x)   # 2
```

Comment: It should be (B - A).days to get the accurate diff