# Python date check

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm hoping to create a program that takes todays date and a given date in the future and finds the difference in days between those two dates. I'm not too sure as to how I would go about doing this and I have very little experience using datetime.

From what I've been trying and reading up, I need to import datetime, and then grab todays date. After that, I need to take an input from the user for the day, month and year that they want in the future, and to make a check that the current year is less than the future year. After that, I'll need to do a calculation in the difference in days between them and print that to the screen.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: actually, what you mentioned is valid way to do it? so what is ur question? how to write the code?

Comment: Yes, I have no idea as to how I'd go about writing it, since I know very little about datetime

Comment: *Try something*.  I highly recommend opening the Python interactive console and playing around with objects. I do this all the time when I'm learning how to use a new module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Days between two dates in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258432/days-between-two-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

here a hint for you small program using `datetime` and `time`:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime  
>>> today_time = time.time()
>>> today_time
1415848116.311676
>>> today_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(today_time)
>>> today_time
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 8, 38, 36, 311676)
>>> future_time = input("Enter Year,month,day separeted by space:")
Enter Year,month,day separeted by space:2015 06 24
>>> year,month,day = future_time.split()
>>> diff = datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day)) - today_time
>>> diff.days
222
```

you can use `datetime.date` but instead asking user current date, you can have it from the system using `time.time`