# Differences between two dates in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import date
import random    
earlier_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(1, 25))    
later_date = date(2017, 6, random.randint(earlier_date.day + 1, 28))    
days_between = (later_date - earlier_date)    
print("There are",days_between,"days between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)
```

The output i have (full difference)

```
There are 18 days, 0:00:00 days between 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-19
```

The Output I want (day difference only)

```
There are 3 days between 2017-06-22 and 2017-06-25
```

Comment: Duplicates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258432/days-between-two-dates

Comment: What is the problem ? You choose random dates, how could you expect a specifif result ?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, it always pick 2 dates, and show the day differences

Comment: There are 18 days, 0:00:00 days between 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-19
 this is the output  i am getting ...i want output as i mentioned in question

Comment: You may have told us in the post at first time. Because I get exact number of date personnally

Comment: @azro i dont want specific result.. i  want my code to be in a format that i mentioned

Comment: Look the edit I've made to your post, to understand how it should be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Answer (score 2):

Use `days_between.days` to the days difference. I've also add a *s-check* for `day` grammar

```
# String parts
print("There are", days_between.days, "day" + ('s' if days_between.days > 1 else '') +
      " between", earlier_date, "and", later_date)

# f-string
print(f"There are {days_between.days} day{'s' if days_between.days > 1 else ''} "
      f"between {earlier_date} and {later_date}")
```