# Days between dates format in print error in python

Tags: python, datetime-format

Calculating days between two datetimes, I have:

```
import datetime

...
days_late = curr_date-last_date
diff_days = days_late.days
print(diff_days)
```

which prints **-9**

Then I try to format the output using:

```
print("Days left: {}").format(diff_days)
```

I get **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'**

How can I fix it?

Comment: `print("Days left: {}".format(6))`

Comment: u were one parenthesis away to not post this question

Comment: use datetime.timedelta(), Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258432/days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to format the `string` not the `print`.

```py
print("Days left: {}".format(diff_days))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use the `format` generator on the `print()` function.
instead use

`print("Days left: {}".format(diff_days))`.