# How can I get the difference in days between today and a previous date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to get the difference (in days) between today and a previous date here:

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today() # get today's date
print("Today's date:", today)
new_today = today.strftime("%Y, %#m, %Y") # convert it so that delta.days understands
print(new_today)

f_date = date(new_today)
l_date = date(2014, 7, 11)
delta = f_date - l_date
print(delta.days)
```

But I get an error:
`TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`

I've read [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258432/days-between-two-dates) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates) on this, but they don't address using today's date in the calculation.

What's the best way to perform this calculation?

Comment: What exactly are you seeking to get with the difference in dates? Are you just seeking the difference in amount of days between the dates?

Comment: @Paul In days. I've edited my question to make that clear, thank you.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Not really, as using today's date as a date object isn't covered, and that's what I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `datetime`

```
import datetime
x = datetime.date.today()
y = datetime.date(2014, 7, 11)  
diff = x-y
print(diff.days)
```

output

```
2392
```