# Create timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new to Python.

Would like to know how to create a timestamp variable.

```
list_compute_date[0:10]
Out[23]: 
[Timestamp('2021-05-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-27 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-23 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-22 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-19 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-04-16 00:00:00')]
```

I have the list_compute_date as above, now I would to create a variable as below:

```
today = Timestamp('2021-04-28 00:00:00')
```

and then:

```
x = list_compute_date[0] - today

print(x) is 6 days.
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Is that a `pandas.Timestamp` object ? Why not use datetime.datetime objetcs ,

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258465/5474196 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/22924683/5474196

Comment: @arzo thanks. Exactly that's one!

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime.now()
print('timestamp:', timestamp)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html