# How to compare an objects in a list to another object that is in the same list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime, tuples

`nrmcdate` is a list in an order of name, class, and date. This list represents the class the student did not attend and the date which the student did not attend. eg `(john, 5537, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15, 0, 0))` means john did not attend class 5537 at 15-5-2021

`registered_lists` is the list of student that have registered to that class. So in this list there will be repeating names. eg. `('JOHN', 5537), ('JOHN', 5620)` means john has registered to class 5620 and 5537.

```
nrmcdate = [
    ('JOHN', 5537, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15, 0, 0)),
    ('JOHN', 5620, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15, 0, 0)),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5537, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 3, 0, 0)),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5537, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 10, 0, 0)),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5558, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0)),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5563, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 12, 0, 0)),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5628, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 20, 0, 0)),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5628, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 8, 0, 0)),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5531, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 7, 0, 0)),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5531, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 14, 0, 0)),
    ("['KSPKGRMQSNSO']", 5558, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 11, 0, 0)),
    ("['KSPKGRMQSNSO']", 5558, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 3, 0, 0)),
    ("['KSPKGRMQSNSO']", 5558, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 8, 0, 0)),
    ("['KSPKGRMQSNSO']", 5558, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 0, 0)),
    ("['KSPKGRMQSNSO']", 5558, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 30, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5530, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 7, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5530, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 9, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5530, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5530, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5540, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 28, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5540, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 11, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5541, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 27, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5541, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 7, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5541, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)),
    ("['NSPZOPGXWZTEWQZPSHZKSJIZK']", 5546, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 6, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5531, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 14, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5532, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 3, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5532, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5535, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 21, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5556, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 13, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5561, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 11, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5561, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 29, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5561, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 13, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5620, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 30, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5626, datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5643, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 29, 0, 0)),
    ("['NZAZJPGXWZTEKSWKZOSZKZAJZV']", 5643, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 10, 0, 0)),
    # Many more rows...
]
```

and

```
registered_list = [
    ('JOHN', 5537),
    ('JOHN', 5620),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5531),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5534),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5537),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5554),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5558),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5563),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5620),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5624),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5628),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5631),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5632),
    ('["KSXXGPSPZQWTS\'SVZCIXZOOZQGO"]', 5635),
    ('["KZGD\'GPUKJTQEZTQ"]', 5618),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5531),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5533),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5536),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5542),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5544),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5548),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5554),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5557),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5562),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5620),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5623),
    ("['ASAZPGXWZKSWKZBASJQZCI']", 5627),
    ("['BZAZJGQEKSO']", 5643),
    ("['BZAZJGQEKSO']", 5645),
    ("['BZAZJGQEKSO']", 5647),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5530),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5554),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5559),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5564),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5598),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5599),
    ("['CEISJQY,UKSCKZSHUK']", 5642),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5531),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5533),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5536),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5542),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5544),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5548),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5554),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5557),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5562),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5620),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5623),
    ("['CZJ,SGJSZNQMI']", 5627),
    ("['CZOJTQIKZE']", 5543),
    ("['CZOJTQIKZE']", 5547),
    ("['CZOJTQIKZE']", 5551),
    ("['CZOJTQIKZE']", 5555),
    ("['UKZSDSHQMU']", 5626),
    ("['UKZSDSHQMU']", 5643),
    ("['UKZSDSHQMU']", 5644),
    ("['UKZSDSHQMU']", 5646),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5538),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5540),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5541),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5620),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5624),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5626),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5631),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5633),
    ("['VOPZOZRM/IOSIZVXTOZQMO']", 5636),
    ("['VVSEZPXWZKSWSJESVXZOOZQGO']", 5542),
    ("['VVSEZPXWZKSWSJESVXZOOZQGO']", 5544),
    ("['VVSEZPXWZKSWSJESVXZOOZQGO']", 5548),
    ("['VVSEZPXWZKSWSJESVXZOOZQGO']", 5555),
    ("['VVSEZPXWZKSWSJESVXZOOZQGO']", 5557),
    ("['ZSJZNZAXQMOWJSZQGAXZOOZQGO']", 5627)
]
```

Currently I am required to compare the dates of nrmcdate to itself and see if the dates are 3 days apart. eg.(not from the list above) `[(Aang, 12, datetime.datetime(2021, 05, 15)),( Ben, 22, datetime.datetime(2021, 05, 12)]` since the objects in the list is three days apart it will then take the name and compare to the registerd_lists. Once the two name have a match in the registered list, the programme will then  check to see if Aang and Ben have a common class. output eg. `(Aang, Ben , 16)` this means Aang and Ben is in the same class 16.

I have been trying to figure out how to compare the dates for the past few weeks and i hope someone here could give a solution.

Comment: You could use nested loops to compare each pair of objects in the `nrmcdate` list to see if they are 3 days apart. This is not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Please review my edit and try to include a minimum set of data that will illustrate your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258432/days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by listing all the pairs

```
itertools.combinations(nrmcdate, 2) # don't forget to import
```

Then for all pairs

```
def common_class(pair, registered):
    person1 = pair[0]
    person2 = pair[1]
    if (abs((person1[2] - person2[2]).days) >= 3): #check if 3 days apart
        if common_classes := set(registered[person1[0]]).intersection(registered[person2[0]]): # they have a common class
            return (person1[0], person2[0], common_classes)
    return None
```

at last convert `registered_list` to a dict using:

```
result_dict = {}
for x in registered_list:
    result_dict.setdefault(x[0], []).append(x[1])
```

then to put this all toghether:

```
import datetime
import itertools

nrmcdate = [("Aang", 12, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15)),( "Ben", 22, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12))]
registered_list = [('Ben', 5537), ('Aang', 5537)]

itertools.combinations(nrmcdate, 2)

def common_class(pair, registered):
    person1 = pair[0]
    person2 = pair[1]
    if (abs((person1[2] - person2[2]).days) >= 3): #check if 3 days apart
        if common_classes := set(registered[person1[0]]).intersection(registered[person2[0]]): # they have a common class
            return (person1[0], person2[0], common_classes)
    return None

result_dict = {}
for x in registered_list:
    result_dict.setdefault(x[0], []).append(x[1])

print([res for x in itertools.combinations(nrmcdate, 2) if (res := common_class(x, result_dict))]) # we at last check if the value is not none
```

I hope this works, it isn't really tested. For example if a name is in nrmcdate but not in registered_list, it would crash but it's not that hard to fix.