# How do I convert a datetime.date object into datetime.datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a datetime.date object into a datetime.datetime object with zeros for any missing time attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192814/convert-a-datetime-date-object-into-a-datetime-datetime-object-with-zeros-for-an)

How do I convert a `datetime.date` obj into `datetime.datetime` obj, defaulting to midnight?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`datetime.combine` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) with an empty [`time` instance](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.time):

```
dateobject = datetime.date.today()
datetime.datetime.combine(dateobject, datetime.time())
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`datetime.time.min` constant](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.min):

```
datetime.datetime.combine(dateobject, datetime.time.min)
```

Both `datetime.time()` and `datetime.time.min` represent midnight (00:00:00).