# Converting string to date object without time info

Tags: python

I'd like to convert a string to a Python date-object. I'm using `d = datetime.strptime("25-01-1973", "%d-%m-%Y")`, as per the documentation on https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html, and that yields `datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 25, 0, 0)`.

When I use `d.isoformat()`, I get `'1973-01-25T00:00:00'`, but I'd like to get `1973-01-25` (without the time info) as per the docs:

```
date.isoformat()
Return a string representing the date in ISO 8601 format, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’. For example, date(2002, 12, 4).isoformat() == '2002-12-04'.
```

It is understood I can use SimpleDateFormat etc., but since the `isoformat()` example is explicitly mentioned in the docs, I'm not sure why I'm getting the unwanted time info after the date.

I guess I'm missing a detail somewhere?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The object that is returned by `datetime.datetime.strptime` is a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object rather than a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object. As such it will have the time information included and when `isoformat()` is called will include this information.

You can use the [`datetime.datetime.date()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python) method to convert it to a `date` object as below.

```
import datetime as dt

d = dt.datetime.strptime("25-01-1973", "%d-%m-%Y")

# Convert datetime object to date object.
d = d.date()

print(d.isoformat())
# 1973-01-25
```