# I need to convert datetime to date without seconds in python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I need to convert datetime to date without seconds in python, how to execute this:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('2016-06-01 16:05:20', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
print dt
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 5, in <module>
    dt = datetime.strptime('2016-06-01 16:05:20', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  16:05:20
```

I've tried everything
Can help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert datetime to date (in Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python)

Comment: *"I've tried everything"* - where *is* what you've tried, then? Broadly, either: 1. extract just the date part then parse it; or 2. parse the whole thing then call `.date()` to discard the time.

Comment: @BakriBitar The answers there just say to use `.date()`, which he's already doing. His problem is with the parsing.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you're going to discard the time, you still need to include it in your format string, since it exists in the string you're parsing. `strptime()` doesn't know that you don't care about the time, it just needs to match the input against the format string.

```
dt = datetime.strptime('2016-06-01 16:05:20', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
```

Comment: `pedido_data = datetime.datetime.strptime(pedido_data, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime`

Comment: What is the value of `pedido_data`?

Comment: It should be a string like `'2016-06-01 16:05:20'`, but that error indicates that it's already a `datetime`.

Comment: It is already a date time stored in mysql, but I need to remove the second

Comment: You want to remove the second, but leave the hours and minutes?

Comment: The error message indicates that you already parsed it. If so, you should just use `pedido_data.date()`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: That means `pedido_data` contains `None`, not a datetime.

Comment: `pedidos = con.cursor.fetchall() for pedido in pedidos: pedido_data = pedido[4]`

Comment: I guess that row of the database table contains `NULL` in this column.

Comment: `print pedido_data` response `2016-06-01 16:05:20`

Comment: Either edit your question or post a new question. I can't answer you like this.