# python datetime remove minute and second information

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime array which has hour, minute and second information. I want to remove the minute and second infromation from it and change the hour to the next hour.

i.e. 
peak_interval

```
array([datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 13, 6, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 12, 7, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 23, 16, 45),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 17, 15)], dtype=object)
```

I want to obtain the following:

```
peak_interval
array([datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 13, 7, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 12, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 23, 17, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 18, 0)], dtype=object)
```

I can write some kind of for loop but I am trying to use some smart method if possible.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python
Keep in mind, though, that the result in that case would be a date object.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can easily modify just a few fields using [`datetime.datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)

```
old_date = datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 23, 16, 45)
new_date = old_date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: Hi @KevinMGranger, it's replacing `minutes`, and `seconds` with `0`, can we completely remove this information from datetime?

Comment: @AbdulRehman a `datetime` by definition has a `date` and a `time`. If you don't want time information, use a `date`. You can convert a `datetime` by calling `datetime.date()`.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `timedelta` from `datetime`:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
def reset(dt):
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(hours = 1, minutes = -dt.minute, seconds = -dt.second)

np.vectorize(reset)(peak_interval)

# array([datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 13, 7, 0),
#        datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 12, 8, 0),
#        datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 23, 17, 0),
#        datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 18, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
now = datetime.now()
now2 = datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour)
```