# date conversion from list in python

Tags: python, date, comparison

I am new to Python, I have list l with 8th element like this, I want this to be compared with, Coding like this. Can some body let me know, is this right way of comparing string to time format?

```
>>> l[7]
'07APR2015'
>>> import time
>>> td= time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
>>> td
'20170227'
>>> l[7]>td
False
>>> l[7]<td
True
>>> tt ='02APR2015'
>>> tt > td
False
>>> tt < td
True
```

If not, please suggest me in conversion.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `'07APR2015'` is a string. You're comparing as strings, which may seem like it works sometimes, but it's not! you have to parse the date first.

Comment: Can you help me how do i do?

Comment: problem is you have to provide a list of months abbreviations first for all your months (I don't know which system issues those dates).

Comment: It is the format in SAS, this date9. format in SAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as say in the comment you need to convert the string to a datetime

take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) , you have an exemple how to convert date

a solution can be (in python 3) :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime_object = datetime.strptime('07APR2015', '%d%b%Y')                   
>>> datetime_object
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 0, 0)
>>> now = datetime.now()                                      
>>> now < datetime_object
False
>>> now > datetime_object
True
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you, but now is giving me seconds also, which i dont need, I would like to compare with date part of now, can you help me with that? Thanks ! again

Comment: You can get the date object from a datetime : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python

Comment: Thank you, This really helps