# How to format datetime object to date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a datetime object

```
v = 21.01.2019 14:25:37
```

I want to convert above datetime object to date as this

```
a = convert(v)
a = 21.01.2019
```

how i can do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert datetime to date (in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want today's date.try this :

```
datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

If you want your datetime object date :

```
v.date()
```