# Python Flask date conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restful

I need to convert DateTime to Date in Python.

How to convert the DateTime 2020-04-14T18:30:00.000Z to date 2020-04-14 in Python Flask?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert datetime to date (in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways which you could do this, however, I will only focus on one.
You can use:

```
import datetime
date = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:10]

print(date)
```

this code should yield a date in this format: `YYYY/MM/DD`.
This works because you are essentially, by using `[:10]`, cutting off all characters after character 9 of the string. For example,

```
X = "hello, world!"
# and then doing
print(X[:2])
```

would return:

```
he
```

Hope this answers your question!