# How to convert datetime to date only? (Odoo13)

Tags: python, odoo

I want to display the Date in dd/MM/yyyy format instead of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

When I used : `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, format doesn't change.

```
date = fields.Datetime('Date', default=fields.Datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Of course, you only change the default. Try changing `fields.Datetime` to `fields.Date`

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python>
Sorry, I would have used a comment if I could.

Comment: You want to change the date format for one field? And if you dont want the time we declare it as datetime field?!! Could you explain what are you doing exacly

Answer (score 3):

The format used to display `Date` and `Datetime` fields is defined depending on the type of the widget, you can check that in the [init function](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/widgets/date_picker.js#L32):

```
format : this.type_of_date === 'datetime' ? time.getLangDatetimeFormat() : time.getLangDateFormat()
```

The `datetime` widget extends the date widget and [defines its type](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/widgets/date_picker.js#L341) to `datetime`.

To force the `Datetime` field to display its value using the date format, try to set the `widget` attribute to `date`.

```
<field name='date' widget='date'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Date() function to convert `datetime.datetime` object to `date` object.

like for example you have field `date` which is datetime.datetime object so you can do is, fetch this fields and grab like this `date.date()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```py
date = fields.Date(string='Date', default=fields.Date.context_today)
```

`default=` is setting only value for new objects. It does not change its format.