# How to get date in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am Trying to get the current date
This is my code

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)
```

But I need Only Date not date and Time both

Comment: datetime.datetime.now().date()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a datetime to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date)

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(x)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.