# Extract the first 10 values of a column and create a new one

Tags: pandas, database, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-wrangling

I hope you can help me:)
I have:

```
| ID         | Process        | Date       
|21320387hisf  | f490efi4r    | 2021-04-10 13:19:57.34656 
| qwehi2uh3e29  | 12387193t    | 2021-08-10 19:16:58.34765
```

I want:

```
| ID            |  Process     | Date                       |New_date
| 21320387hisf  | f490efi4r    | 2021-04-10 13:19:57.34656  |2021-04-10
| qwehi2uh3e29  | 12387193t    | 2021-08-10 19:16:58.34765  |2021-08-10
```

So I want to create a new column with just the Date and without the time.
Anything I tried seems to not work. Column Date is not a string.

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date

Comment: use `df['New_Date']=df['Date'].dt.normalize()`

Comment: This one : 
`df['New_date'] = df['Date'].dt.date` works for me.