# Convert to datetime to then groupby month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have data (labeled as `df`) that looks like this(below) where the 'DATE' column is formatted as such -> MM/DD/YYYY.

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REssk.png)

I then need to group the available accident data by month.

Anyone know how to do this by first converting 'DATE' column to a `datetime` type, setting the index using `set_index` and then using `groupby` to group by month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is not is not already in datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then, do following to groupby month:

```
df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month)[columns_you_need_to_groupby_on].mean()
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you [How do I convert a datetime to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date?rq=1)

I looked at your table and it looks like you could just sort the table by date and you'd be fine