# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new to Python and am learning LSTM using Pandas with a sample project that I've modified from Github to use with my own data. I am running it on Kaggle.

For reference, the project is found here: https://github.com/abaranovskis-redsamurai/automation-repo/blob/master/forecast-lstm/forecast_lstm_shampoo_sales.ipynb

My data is simply a csv with dates and sales. Here's what the first few lines look like, with the date being YYYY-MM:

```
"date","num"
"1995-12",700
"1996-1",500
"1997-2",1300
"1996-3",2800
"1996-4",3500
```

The error I am getting says that "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'".

The code is here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


def parser(x):
    return pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m')

df = pd.read_csv('../input/smalltestb/smalltest1b.csv', parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)
df.tail()

train = df

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train)
train = scaler.transform(train)
n_input = 12
n_features = 1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train, train, length=n_input, batch_size=6)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
```

Finally, the error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_35/785266029.py in <module>
     25 
     26 scaler = MinMaxScaler()
---> 27 scaler.fit(train)
     28 train = scaler.transform(train)
     29 n_input = 12

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    334         # Reset internal state before fitting
    335         self._reset()
--> 336         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    337 
    338     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    369         X = self._validate_data(X, reset=first_pass,
    370                                 estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
--> 371                                 force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    372 
    373         data_min = np.nanmin(X, axis=0)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    418                     f"requires y to be passed, but the target y is None."
    419                 )
--> 420             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    421             out = X
    422         else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    596                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    597                 else:
--> 598                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    599             except ComplexWarning:
    600                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1991 
   1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1994 
   1995     def __array_wrap__(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

So, I decided to run just the import part and look at the head in another notebook. It didn't format correctly

```
    date    num
0   1995-12-01 00:00:00 700
1   1996-01-01 00:00:00 500
2   1996-02-01 00:00:00 1300
3   1996-03-01 00:00:00 2800
4   1997-04-01 00:00:00 3500
```

This is definitely not what I wanted (wanted YYYY-MM) and I know it's saved as such. I know this must be from the parser and it's not saving it to the dataframe in the way that I am expecting.

How do I address this? As a note, the guy on Github had this for is parser but it choked when I tried it:

```
def parser(x):
    return pd.datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')

df = pd.read_csv('shampoo.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, date_parser=parser)
```

(He added '190' to the last digit of a year with a dash and a month number whereas I am using a year dash month number.)

Any suggestions? Thanks for having a look!
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [In Python, how do you convert a `datetime` object to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7852855/5987) will help.

Comment: The error message already tells you it's a `datetime.datetime` object, so that's obviously what the parser is turning it into.  You can either format that directly into a string, or you can use the link I gave you to turn it into some number of seconds.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for adding.  I just need the parser to recognize that my data is already in YYYY-MM format and in quotes. My original data doesn't have time, even though the parser inserted "00:00:00" into the data, which I didn't want or even put into my parse statement.  I'm not sure why this is happening. I see that the post is about time but didn't see an example of just grabbing the year and month. I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date but I don't see how to use it in parsing. I did try strftime but that choked.

Comment: I just want datetime.date, no times. How do I get that part? My original data has no seconds or times.

Comment: A `datetime.datetime` always has hours, minutes, and seconds, but if you don't specify them they're always 0.  `strftime` lets you specify a formatting string, you should be able to get whatever you want.

Comment: Ah! Well, when I added .date() to the end of my parse statement and tested it, the data showed in the right format. However, when I went back to add to my code to run the script, it gives "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'". The other guy's script worked without having this error. What could be the problem?

Comment: The error message is very clear - it says you need to provide an int or a string (specifically a string that looks like a floating point number).  You're providing neither.  Fix that.

Comment: As error message says argument must be int or string. You can not feed date time format as it is to model. You need to parse the data time. Use `tfa.text.parse_time`, which Parse an input string according to the provided format string into a Unix time. For more information about library read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/text/parse_time). Thanks!