# How to convert a datetime to date in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, tableau-api

I'm getting today's date & other datetime date is coming in. That datetime I want to convert it to normal date. But it keep throwing errors.

Below is my code.
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

## get todays date

```
today_date = date.today()
#print(today_date)

# get user information from the group
pagination_item = server.groups.populate_users(mygroup)

# print the names of the users
for user in mygroup.users:
    # user.last_login is present in datetime format, converted that to date format
    #lastlogin = datetime.date(user.last_login) 
    **lastlogin = user.last_login.date()**
    print(type(lastlogin))
# difference between today & last login date
    difference = today_date - lastlogin
    if difference.days > 120:
        print(user.name,lastlogin,difference)
```

Errror which I'm getting

**<class 'datetime.date'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Bhavana\user_list_90_days.py", line 37, in 
lastlogin = user.last_login.date()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'**

Comment: Are you sure that all of your users have a `last_login` at all?  Your error indicates that one of your `last_login`s is of `NoneType` (so empty).

Comment: Hi,
Yes not everytime we get last_login, so yes thay are empty for some users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a datetime to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this

```py
from datetime import datetime  
datetime_obj = datetime.now()
  
print(datetime_obj)
  
date = datetime_obj.date()

print(date)
```

Output shall be:

```
2021-08-07 06:30:20.227879

2021-08-07
```