# Not able to get only date from datetime

Tags: python, pandas

```
def arrange_by_date():
    df = pd.read_excel("logfile_Final_test.xlsx")
    df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=True).set_index('Date').last('3M')
    df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False)
    df.to_excel("Master_logfile.xlsx", index=True)


arrange_by_date()
```

**Data in excel sheet in the form of**

```
  Database         Date       Time         Description
Some_DB_name    2022-12-25   some_time    Some_Description
Some_DB_name    2023-01-14   some_time    Some_Description
    ..             ..           ..              ..
Some_DB_name    2022-11-19   some_time    Some_Description
```

**Expected Output**

```
      Database         Date        Time         Description
    Some_DB_name    2023-01-14   some_time    Some_Description
    Some_DB_name    2022-12-25   some_time    Some_Description
        ..             ..           ..              ..
    Some_DB_name    2022-11-19   some_time    Some_Description
```

**Output I am getting in Excel sheet**

```
       Date             Database        Time        Description
2023-01-14 00:00:00    Some_DB_name   some_time    Some_Description
2022-12-25 00:00:00    Some_DB_name   some_time    Some_Description
    ..           ..           ..              ..
2022-11-19 00:00:00    Some_DB_name   some_time    Some_Description
```

my Date Column is getting shift towards start with `00:00:00`

Comment: What difference does it make? You have a new datetime column that records hours, mins and seconds. If you want your format, keep it as a string

Comment: how to remove `00:00:00`

Comment: Again, what difference does it make? You already had that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a datetime to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date)

Comment: .dt.normalize()

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @roganjosh, it shouldn't make any difference but if you must have just the date and drop the time element because your 'date column is the df index, you can use:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].date
```